# MySQL Workbench 6.17 error Ubuntu 12.04 x64

Tags: 12.04, mysql, mysql-workbench

Im trying to run MySQL Workbench Migration to transfer a table from MS SQL to MySQL.

Using the latest version of workbench (or in fact any of the latest ones), the migration fails instantly and gives me this error:

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18: no version information available      
(required by /usr/bin/wbcopytables)

relocation error: /usr/bin/wbcopytables: symbol mysql_options4, version  
libmysqlclient_18 not defined in file libmysqlclient.so.18 with link time  
reference

ERROR: Copy helper exited with an error: Worker exited with status 127
```

If I try and use the shell script that workbench generates (to carry out the transfer), I get this error instead:

```
/usr/bin/wbcopytables: error while loading shared libraries: libwbbase.so: cannot 
open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Transfer works fine with an older version, but Im having another issue with that now (its not transferring all the rows of the table, it always stops at a certain point)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_options4` was only added on mysql 5.6.6. You will need a newer version of libmysqlclient.

i would suggest installing it from ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6